# Quiero buscar hashtag de acuerdo con la geolocalización usando tweepy

Tags: python, geolocalización, tweepy

Estoy trabajando con Python y Tweepy. Logre permitir geolocalizarse mediante coordenadas ingresadas por el usuario. Pero ahora lo que quiero es buscar hashtags segun geolocalizacion. Tenes alguna idea de como puedo hacer esto?

Esto es lo que hice hasta ahora:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key='**********'
consumer_secret='************'
access_token='************'
access_token_secret='***********'
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api= tweepy.API(auth)



'''funcion para geolocalizacion'''
def geolocalizacion(api):
    latitud=float(input("ingrese la latitud: "))
    longitud=float(input("ingrese la longitud: "))
    precicion=float(input("ingrese el rango de precicion: "))
    ubicacion=api.reverse_geocode(latitud,longitud,precicion)
    return(Ubicacion)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favpr, corrige el título a la brevedad para que la pregunta no sea cerrada.